# How to export account portfolio information at Interactive Brokers

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ib-api

I would like to use a dataframe to store my portfolio information and update every minute.
But the outcome is empty from the below code, am I missing something?

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.ticktype import TickTypeEnum
import pandas as pd
import time


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):


    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.all_positions = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['ConID', 'Symbol', 'Quantity', 'Average Cost', 'MarketPrice', 'marketValue', 'unrealizedONL', 'realizedPNL'])

    def updatePortfolio(self, contract: Contract, position: float, marketPrice: float, marketValue: float,averageCost: float, unrealizedPNL: float, realizedPNL:float, accountName:str):
        super().updatePortfolio(contract, position, marketPrice, marketValue, averageCost, unrealizedPNL, realizedPNL, accountName)
        index = str(contract.conId)
        self.all_positions.loc[index] = contract.conId, contract.symbol, position, averageCost, marketPrice, marketValue, unrealizedPNL, realizedPNL


def main():

    app = IBapi()
    app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 0)
    app.reqAccountUpdates(True, "XXXXXXXX")
    current_positions = app.reqAccountUpdates(True, "XXXXXXX")

    app.run()
    print(current_positions.to_string())
    app.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`reqAcccountUpdates` is an asynchronous function call - it sends an outgoing message but does not wait for a response. (Since the message initiates a subscription to a data stream, there isn't a single response returned but instead a series of responses).

So `current_positions` in:

```
current_positions = app.reqAccountUpdates(True, "XXXXXXX")
```

will always be None. Instead the responses are stored in `app.all_positions` by the overridden `updatePortfolio()` function.

Also, the `run()` loop is an infinite loop so the lines after that won't execute. Most commonly this type of architecture would be handled by python futures/the asyncio module (as in the [ib_insync](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync) library), or with an additional thread for the run loop.